# Protect window.opener from change

Tags: javascript, window.opener

There is a JavaScript code that opens new page which tries to change the mother-page with the help of window.opener. I need to Protect mother-page from any change. Any advice on how to do it?

Code like this needs to be blocked

`window.opener.location.href='http://google.com/';`

Comment: No script, no comment. What does the script do? If on the same server you can edit the script. If not on the same server it cannot change the opener

Comment: very rightly said by mplungjan.

Comment: basically the question is if I can stop any script of type "window.opener"?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot stop executing "window.opener" but what you can do is assign the opener function to a different variable and mock the original one.

```
window.opener_old = window.opener;
window.opener = function(){};
```

If some other script tries to execute window.opener, the new empty function is going to be called and nothing will happen.

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't control the child page.  How can you protect the mother page if the child is not under your control?